# Htacces mod_rewrite sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with my .htaccess mod_rewrite. I've made a simple custom CMS and i've put this in a sub directory of my domain; http://www.example.com/cms

I've got the following situations:

cms/index.php?page=modules/pages/index.php
**convert to**
cms/modules/pages/index

and
cms/index.php?page=modules/pages/edit.php?id=1
**convert to**
cms/modules/pages/edit/1

I've got it working with a subdomain, but when i use example.com/cms it doesn't do anything

i've made this .htaccess but i couldn't get it working...

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]



RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/cms/([^/]*)/$ cms/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/cms/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/cms/pages/([^/]*)/$ /cms/index.php?page=pages/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/cms/pages/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=pages/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/cms/modules/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /cms/index.php?page=modules/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/cms/modules/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=modules/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/cms/modules/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=modules/$1/$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What should it be doing? If I give it a URL, what should the desired output be?

Comment: I've edited the post, i hope i'm clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in an htaccess file, the URI's have their prefix removed (the leading slash), so those patterns won't match anything. Either remove the leading slash from the pattern or make it optional (with a `?`):

```
RewriteRule ^/?cms/([^/]*)/$ cms/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?cms/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?cms/pages/([^/]*)/$ /cms/index.php?page=pages/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?cms/pages/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=pages/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?cms/modules/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /cms/index.php?page=modules/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?cms/modules/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=modules/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?cms/modules/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /cms/index.php?page=modules/$1/$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Additionally, your first rule can be simplified to just:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Damn, didn't know that the solution was so easy! Thanks for your answer!!